# angular library node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

So ive created the following library:

[image]

Now as you can see there are some red underlines.

Within this package i wish to use other npm packages (such as `ionic`, `crypto` ect)

I tried to modify the `package.json` inside the library:

```
{
  "name": "sdk-mobil-login-light",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "sha256": "0.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

However i am not quite sure how to use these? what can i do if my code relies on these modules?

Comment: With peerDependencies you are required to download those packages yourself (the user consuming your library needs to download those packages, it doesn't come bundled with your library). So you will need to install those libraries manually in-order for you to use them

Comment: @c_ogoo is there a way i can say that those are required for using the module?

Comment: Essentially thats what peerDependencies are for. But it doesn't download it for you. When installing your library, the user will get a console warning like that a peer dependency is not installed

Comment: @c_ogoo thank you that makes sense can you post it as an answer so i can reward you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `peerDependencies` you are required to download those packages yourself (the user consuming your library needs to download those packages, it doesn't come bundled with your library).

So you will need to install those libraries manually in-order for you to use them.

If a user installs your library without those dependencies already installed, they will get a warning in their console.

> By adding a package in peerDependencies you are saying:
> My code is compatible with this version of the package.

> If this package already exists in node_modules, do nothing.

> If this package doesn’t already exist in the node_modules directory or it is the wrong version, don’t add it. But, show a warning to the user that it wasn’t found.

*Extract from https://indepth.dev/posts/1187/npm-peer-dependencies*

Comment: Your link is down